# "We liaise very close" or "We liaise very closely"?

Tags: grammar

I've seen "we liaise very close" in a textbook. How come an adjective is used?

Comment: 'Liaise close' is rare on the internet and is more probably an attempt at a flat adverb construction than a descriptive (adjective) construction. 'Liaise closely' is grammatical and idiomatic. I'd class it as an error.

Comment: It sounds pretty strange indeed. Thank you.

Comment: How would you liaise at a distance ?

Comment: Not all adverbs end in -ly. Search this site and/or the wider web for 'flat adverbs'.

Comment: @NigelJ This forum would be a good example …

Answer (score -1):

Arguably, it should be *liaise very **closely.***

It is true that *close* can work as an adverb in some constructions. In these cases, it has a meaning of 'in a close position or manner':

> *Don't drive so **close** to the car in front of you.
>  
>   Look **close** and tell me what you see.
>
>   They sat **close** together on the bench.*
>                                                                    [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close)

However, it seems that it is not normally used that way with *liaise.*

**Discussion**

If you search [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liaise+very+closely%2Cliaise+very+close&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cliaise%20very%20closely%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cliaise%20very%20closely%3B%2Cc0), the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (COCA), or the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) (BNC), you find no hits for *liaise very **close***. In all three sources, you find one hit for *liaise very **closely,*** so these results are not definitive.

Results for *liaise **close*** vs *liaise **closely*** are similar. None of the three sources return any hits for  *liaise **close.*** COCA also returns none for *liaise **closely,*** but BNC returns two, and google Ngrams returns more than one.

If you search google books, however, you find just one hit for *liaise very **close*** ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=XTOQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22liaise+very+close%22&dq=%22liaise+very+close%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFwpOioKnmAhVhpVkKHcKPDjAQ6AEwAHoECAAQAw), in fact used as *liaise very **close by***). On the other hand, if you search for *liaise very **closely,*** you find quite a few hits. Here are some examples:

*I recently took an initiative to write to my colleagues and say we need to **liaise very closely** to make sure that business doesn't fall through the gaps.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wr4IyhpPd7gC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=RA1-PA21&dq=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&pg=RA1-PA21#v=onepage&q=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&f=false)
*That is rough guidance, but we **liaise very closely** so that we can make two and two add up to five.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=DUV8Q0LQ3bMC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=RA1-PA25&dq=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&pg=RA1-PA25#v=onepage&q=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&f=false)
*We **liaise very closely** with tax authorities right across the world who are grappling with the same businesses as us.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=GtZh7H_FSe8C&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=RA1-PA29&dq=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&pg=RA1-PA29#v=onepage&q=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&f=false)
*It is important to **liaise very closely** with the gas supplier to establish procedures to minimize lead times.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=c5Tlps0XgNEC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT722&dq=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&pg=PT722#v=onepage&q=%22liaise%20very%20closely%22&f=false)

An overwheliming majority of examples come from debates in the UK Parliament.

Comment: So? Because it is not on record, it is wrong to use it? And who cares how UK parliamentarians speak?

Comment: @green_ideas The argument is this: if the construction in question is not on record, but an alternative is, and this alternative can be converted, by a simple typo, into the construction in question, then it is reasonable to assume that the construction in question was probably a typo. As far as the bit about parliamentarians, it is there to provide context. It is not unusual for a given construction to be rare outside a particular context, and I believe (though others are of course free to disagree) that it is relevant to mention notable contexts in questions like this.